# SQLite Select Query To Return Last Row For Each Month

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

Have been hacking around with this for way too long.  I tried various approaches using subqueries, `max` function, `group by having`, and `union left join`.

Also read many answers here that resolve - *similar* - but not identical problems. Or, they resolve using features unavailable in SQLite such as procedural logic.

The table below is generated by this query:

```
select strftime(' %Y-%m-%d', datetime(date, 'unixepoch')) as date, quantity from summary order by date
```

| Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-07-20 | 346 |
| 2015-07-30 | 688 |
| 2015-07-31 | 1222 |
| 2015-08-02 | 1291 |
| 2015-08-12 | 1416 |
| 2015-08-28 | 1618 |
| 2015-09-01 | 1618 |
| 2015-09-11 | 1804 |
| 2015-09-29 | 1846 |

Desired result set is the quantity for the last date by month. Date may vary. Given above table, it would be three rows, corresponding to July, August, and September:

| Date | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-07-31 | 1222 |
| 2015-08-28 | 1618 |
| 2015-09-29 | 1846 |

Is there a `select` query that can generate the three rows above?

Here is test data to try this on one's local instance. First, create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE summary (  date integer , quantity integer )
```

Note that I have no choice but to work with date in [Unix Epoch](https://www.epochconverter.com) format. Inserts:

```
insert into summary values (1437408078, 346);
insert into summary values (1438262109, 688);
insert into summary values (1438342858, 1222);
insert into summary values (1438554528, 1291);
insert into summary values (1439405315, 1416);
insert into summary values (1440766612, 1618);
insert into summary values (1441126629, 1618);
insert into summary values (1441968543, 1804);
insert into summary values (1443543335, 1846);
```

Test query to confirm results as per first table above:

```
select strftime(' %Y-%m-%d', datetime(date, 'unixepoch')) as date, quantity from summary order by date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using `group by` to group data by month then get max date and their related quantity as [bare column](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query):

```
SELECT max(strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datetime(date, 'unixepoch'))) as date, quantity
FROM summary
group by strftime('%Y-%m-01', datetime(date, 'unixepoch'))
```

Result :

```
date        quantity
2015-07-31  1222
2015-08-28  1618
2015-09-29  1846
```

A more generic way without using bare columns :

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datetime(date, 'unixepoch')) as date, quantity
FROM summary s
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-01', datetime(date, 'unixepoch')) as month, 
         max(date) as max_date
  FROM summary
  GROUP BY 1
) AS t on t.max_date = s.date
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/4sxv_KOM)

Comment: Wow that is nice and good to know of the db fiddle link!

Comment: This may produce inconsistent results depending on the version of SQLITE. There are several ways to solve the problem correctly - mostly based around a subquery or the max-concat trick. There's also a whole chapter in the MySQL manual - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: @symcbean I'm not sure when bare columns first appeared in sqlLite versions! I have added a more general query to handle it instead of utilizing bare columns.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUSBSTR() to extract only the year and month from the date:

```
SELECT MAX(date), quantity
FROM summary
GROUP BY SUBSTR(date, 1, 7);
```

Note that this query uses "bare columns", which makes it incompatible with most other database engines besides SQLite. For example, in Postgres, I had to use

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (month) date, quantity
FROM (
    SELECT date,
           quantity,
           TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYYMM') AS month
    FROM summary
) AS t ORDER BY month, date DESC;
```

while the more verbose JOIN version seems to be about twice faster:

```sql
SELECT t.date, t.quantity
    FROM summary AS t
    JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(m.date) AS date
        FROM (
            SELECT date, quantity, TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYYMM') AS month
            FROM summary
            ORDER BY date
    ) AS m
    GROUP BY month
) AS t1 ON t.date = t1.date;
```

Comment: `SUBSTR(date, 0, 8)` is undefined. The [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) only specify the behavior for positve numbers starting with 1 for the first character in the string and negative numbers starting with -1 for the last character in the string. You want `SUBSTR(date, 1, 8)` or `SUBSTR(date, 1, 7)`.

Comment: Your answer would benefit from you explaining that you are using SQLite's [bare columns](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query) handling, which makes the query valid and working in SQLite, while it is invalid in other DBMS.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Noted and updated. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, query above returns nine rows rather than the three desired. Will add create table and inserts if you wish to try.

Comment: @MaxMacLeod: I created a table from the output of your first query. You might need to change the SUBSTR to extract the year and month from the timestamp if it's stored in a different format.